# Deploy to a specific machine in group

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Often when trying to deploy to a group of machines, at least one of the machines in the group will fail for one reason or another (offline, application in use, etc..)

Is there a way to selectively deploy to a specific machine in a Deployment group, without putting each machine in its own group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a tag to a machine on the depoyment group configuration.

After that, specify the tag at the release deployment group phase.

This will make the release to choose all machine within the group deployment that match you tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter machines through tags:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This seems like a seriously combersome process to go through because one machine wasn't on, when an original deployment was done.

seems odd to me, that you can't do a direct push of a release to a specific machine, without going through some much configuration.